# WinShow not working for ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use the following script in order to show/hide the Slack desktop app for Windows:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, Off
Process, Exist, slack.exe
slackPid = %ErrorLevel%
IfWinNotExist, ahk_pid %slackPid%
{
    WinShow, ahk_pid %slackPid%
}
Else
{
    WinHide, ahk_pid %slackPid%
}
```

The `WinHide` part works correctly, but `WinShow` doesn't show the application, although `%slackPid` is correctly retrieved.

I tried every combination of `WinShow`, `WinActivate` and `WinRestore` with no success.

This script usually works, but it fails with windows of the class `ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`: I tried it with VS code and Rocket.Chat+ which are also apps build on Electron and it fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more than one windows that can be identified by using the process identifier (PID).
To find that out try this AHK code:

```
F1::
list := ""
numberOfwindows := ""
wins := ""
Index := ""
wins2 := ""
Process, Exist, slack.exe
slackPid = %ErrorLevel%
IfWinExist, ahk_pid %slackPid%
    WinHide, ahk_pid %slackPid%
Else
{
    DetectHiddenWindows, On
    WinGet, id, list, ahk_pid %slackPid%
    Loop, %id%
    {
        numberOfwindows := A_Index
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %this_ID%
        wins .= A_Index . ")`ntitle = " title "`n"  "ahk_class ="  " "   class ? A_Index . ")`ntitle = " title "`n" "ahk_class ="  " "  class  "`n`n" : "" 
        If (title = "")
            continue
        WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If !(exStyle & 0x100)
            continue
        Index++
        wins2 .= Index . ")`ntitle = " title "`n"  "ahk_class ="  " "   class ? Index . ")`ntitle = " title "`n" "ahk_class ="  " "  class  "`n`n" : "" 
        WinShow, ahk_id %this_ID%
    }
    MsgBox, number of slack windows = %numberOfwindows%`n`n%wins%`n`nnumber of slack windows with title = %Index%`n`n %wins2%
}
return
```

Replace "slack" with "chrome" in the code to use it for Chrome.

Comment: Indeed, I have 9 windows corresponding to the `slack.exe` process.

Comment: For anyone who stumble upon this, I've chosen a different method than `WinShow` to solve this using the [`TrayIcon.ahk` library](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=1229). All my code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Otiel/24248595ac4b30366a2228a7ac5ec964).